# Searching mySQL column for specific content

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to do a search in my table columns after the content `USER*`, the wildcard is due to different contents which can be `USER4524`etc.

I have tried `contains` and `like`, but nothing really works out for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `LIKE 'USER%'` ?

Comment: I actually tried everything except the % mark. All my methods work now! Thanks..

Comment: the wildcard is '%' in mysql instead the regular '*'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column LIKE 'USER%'
```

Comment: `%` matches 0 or more characters, and `_` matches exactly one character. From [String Comparison Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html).

Comment: @MarcusAdams, thanks for that tip, infact that will be handy in my situation.